# Ember.js - uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'hash' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember.js prototype, which was running fine until now. Since my last deployment I have been consistently getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined.

app.js file

```
// Application
Welcome = Ember.Application.create({
    ready : function() {
    }
});

// Model
Welcome.Ticket = Ember.Object.extend({
    id : null,
    buyerPartyId : null,
    name : null,
    priority : null,
    description : null,
    comment : null
}); 

// Controller
Welcome.ticketsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content : [],

    loadTickets : function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('url here', function(
                data) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < data.serviceRequest.length; i++) {
                self.pushObject(Welcome.Ticket.create(data.serviceRequest[i]));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ticket List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ticket List</h1>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.Button target="Welcome.ticketsController" action="loadTickets"}}
        Load Tickets
    {{/view}}

    {{#each contentBinding="Welcome.ticketsController" tagName="ul"}}
        <b>{{content.id}}</b> - {{content.buyerPartyId}}, <i>{{content.name}}</i>
    {{/each}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure that I am overlooking something simple !! Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Here is the error stack from Chrome dev console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined ember-0.9.5.min.js:13
(anonymous function) ember-0.9.5.min.js:13
(anonymous function)
b.VM.template ember-0.9.5.min.js:9
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.render ember-0.9.5.min.js:12
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.renderToBuffer ember-0.9.5.min.js:12
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.createElement ember-0.9.5.min.js:12
Ember.View.states.preRender.insertElement ember-0.9.5.min.js:12
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.invokeForState ember-0.9.5.min.js:12
c ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
j ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
f.flush ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
f.end ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
Ember.run.end ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
i ember-0.9.5.min.js:10
```

Comment: Might help if you point to which line is throwing the error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, with `{{each}}`, you need to provide the controller directly. Something like:

```
{{#each Welcome.ticketController}}
{{/each}}
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/nVr4r/. Its not throwing the error anymore.

"Load Tickets" button wont work as you dont have a url yet.

Emberjs documentation has a couple of examples using `{{each}}` too. You should take a look.

Also, you might wanna update your emberjs. In the ember world, 0.9.5.min is pretty old :)